# Can't use xlwt to save excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwt

So, I am facing a weird issue, In my code I have the follow snippet:

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

for x in range(len(table)):
    for y in range(len(table[x])):
        sheet.write(x, y, table[x][y])
workbook.save("output.xls")
```

which is from this question's answer: [How do I export a two dimensional list in Python to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954290/how-do-i-export-a-two-dimensional-list-in-python-to-excel)

where table is a multidimentional array (4x12 in my test code) that I want to convert to excel. I know that the code reaches the save and attempts to do, because if I put a directory it cannot save to due to insufficient admin-rights it will give me an error telling me about it, But if I run the code with a normal directory... nothing happens.

I am not sure where this is going wrong

Comment: You're converting x and y to strings unlike the answer you link so should be getting a ValueError... don't do that... eg: `sheet.write(x, y, table[x][y])`

Comment: Yes, I have changed that but I still face the same issue. I will update the code I have at the moment.

Comment: Sure you're not getting any exceptions and are looking in the right place for the output? That code works fine for me with `table = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` for instance

Comment: Make sure you're looking under whatever `os.getcwd()` shows you if you're only use `output.xls` as the name and aren't specifying any other paths...?

Comment: Yes, I am certain as my output has some other information outputted as well. Could my table variable be the issue?

Comment: Let me double check that.

Comment: That appears to have solved the issue, For some reason my program had some random directory it was saving to instead of the program's directory. No idea why.